# Determine missing font for a specific unicode character

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, unicode

There are symbols from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Miscellaneous_Symbols), which are not rendered on my system; as in, they're just rendered as vertical rectangles to mean I do not have the font to display them. This is the case, for instance, of *U+26C4* which should be a snowman-like character, I guess, if I hover with the mouse on it.

If I want to have a unicode character correctly displayed, I think I should install one of the fonts listed [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts), but how can I know which one for each character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to find which font to install for an specific Unicode code point. That is a problem of [coverage](https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts/UnicodeCoverage): which chars are covered by which fonts.

What I could easily say is that a font that covers (almost all) the entire 0 - ffff list of code points (Plane 0) is [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html). Two other fonts with good coverage are The noto family and [Code2000](https://sheet.shiar.nl/font/code2000?q=9728) (you probably don't need Code2001 or Code2002 they cover other areas).

Answer (score 4):

In [Arch official document](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Font_packages) fonts are tagged "*Unicode*" if they have wide Unicode support.

I recommend to install [Linux Libertine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Libertine) and [Noto fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts)

```
pacman -S noto-fonts noto-fonts-emoji ttf-linux-libertine
```

restart your browser after installing new fonts to take effect

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, which helps for the specific _U+26C4_ (and I guess many other characters/emoji in the same "category"), but how could I determine myself which package I need?

Comment: You can start with installing fonts with large coverage of characters and troubleshoot case by case for further issues.