# Showing , , and  in the terminal

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, unicode, rxvt, fontconfig

How can I make (U+1d412), (U+1d43d), and (U+1d441), which I can display clearly in my browser, show in the terminal?

I use Urxvt on Archlinux.

The `~/.Xdefaults` file has this content:

```
URxvt*foreground:       #ffffff
URxvt*background:       #000000
URxvt*font:             xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono:size=12
URxvt*cursorBlink:      true
URxvt*scrollBar:        false
URxvt*scrollTtyOutput:  false
URxvt*saveLines:        50000
URxvt*scrollWithBuffer: true
URxvt*scrollTtyKeypress:true
URxvt.perl-ext-common:  resize-font
URxvt*color4:           #265997
URxvt*color12:          #3F6FD0
```

I know I have to change its 3rd line, but I don't how to know which font can show those symbols, nor if I have it already installed.

I know that the present question is (almost?) a duplicate of [a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/593578/164309) I asked a couple of years ago, however to be honest I'm still totally ignorant on this matter, and none of those answers really gave me a deterministic way to solve the problem of which font I need to install.

At the [*Font*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts) page of Archlinux wiki I read:

> [**List installed fonts for a particular Unicode character**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts#List_installed_fonts_for_a_particular_Unicode_character)
>
> To search for monospace fonts supporting a particular Unicode codepoint:
>
> `fc-match -s monospace:charset=hex-code`

and doing so for the 3 unicodes above gives several results on my system, however I don't know how I should update my `~/.Xdefaults`.

---

For now, what I've tried has been changing the line `URxvt*font:             xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono:size=12` and see what happens.

In fact, I've discovered that [I can try out fonts live in the terminal without changing the configuration above](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rxvt-unicode#Font_declaration_methods) by just entering `printf '\e]710;%s\007' "xft:font-name:pixelsize=12"`, so I've done so for several *`font-name`*s, which I've chosen from `fc-list`'s output, by picking the text between the first and second (i.e. last) `:`, e.g. since `fc-list` has this line

```
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Meslo LG L DZ Regular Nerd Font Complete Mono.ttf: MesloLGLDZ Nerd Font Mono:style=Regular
```

I've entered

```bsh
printf '\e]710;%s\007' "xft:MesloLGSDZ Nerd Font Mono:pixelsize=12"
cat a-file-with-those-three-glyphs-in-it
```

but I keep seeing the boxes meaning the characters can't be shown.

Comment: Does the post [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172811) from thisoldman hep?

Comment: @frabjous, no, it doesn't help me. Or, at least, I don't understand how. I've tried, for instance, to give more than one font to `URxvt*font`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: What fonts did you try? For me,  and  worked with any other fonts I tried with those glyphs as fallback, but  only worked with a couple `URxvt*font:xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono:size=12,xft:Libertinus Math:size=12` and `URxvt*font:xft:DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font Mono:size=12,xft:Sarasa Term K:size=12`; I used your `.Xdefaults` (or other Sarasa variant) as is otherwise.

Comment: After some more tests. Noto Sans Math, FreeSerif and Asana Math also worked.

Comment: I just tested with konsole. It all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the symbols you're using are from the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) block. You're using the DejaVu font. From [the wikipedia page about DejaVu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts#Plane_1:_Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane_(SMP)_Range:_10000-1FFFF_(65,536%E2%80%93131,071)), it supports only 12% of the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block. You need to change the font if you want to display those characters. If you only want to display those three characters, you can use fc-list to find fonts installed on your system like so:

```
fc-list ':charset=1d412 1d43d 1d441'
```

Unfortunately there is no good solution for finding characters in all fonts present in the package manager.

But if you can view the characters in your browser and not in the terminal, you should have a font that supports the character because browsers usually don't have their own fonts.
If you're on Firefox, use the Inspector tool to select the element that's rendering the character and click on Fonts in the rightmost corner of the tool to view what fonts are being used.

Comment: Take for instance ``, which is `U+1D539`. I can see it in my browser. If I use chrome devtools to inspect that character at the beginning of this very comment, I'll see that for that element `font-family` is computed to be `ui-monospace, "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace`, so I would assume one of those listed does the trick. However, when putting `xft:FFF:size=12` in my `.Xdefaults` with `FFF` being any single one of `Cascadia Mono`, `Segoe UI Mono`, and so on, none of them was able to make `` show in the terminal (yes, newly open).